# How to read a value from a USB device in Java?

Tags: java, usb

I'm developing a program, and I have a card reader connected to my Pc with USB, i want to change the value of a variable to the number that i read from the card every time

My code:

```
String cod="0656";//the variable
```

I want to put into cod the string that i read from my card reader, how can I do it?

I'm using the card reader [PCR330](http://gigatms.com.tw/products-detail1.asp?pid=135), no documentation or CD in the box.

Comment: Which card reader do you use? Do they have an API (do they have a library for Java)? Have you looked at the documentation? Can you provide more detail? As this question stands, it is not answerable. You need to add more details.

Comment: I'm using the card reader PCR330, no documentation or CD in the box
Here is the link http://www.gigatms.com.tw/products-detail1.asp?pid=135

Comment: Edit the question with additional information. People don't want to read all the comments to puzzle the question together ;-)

Comment: Your title says something completely different from what your question says.

Comment: previous title had nothing to do with question contents